# I need help extracting the table rows that don't contain "style='display: none;'" in selenium, python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the HTML for the table row I don't want to extract:

```
<tr class="items" data-href="#" style="display: none;">
```

And this is the one I want to extract:

```
<tr class="items" data-href="#" style>
```

> Python 3.10.7,
> Selenium Webdriver 4.17.2

I tried using solutions I found on the internet, but the solutions used an older version of selenium

Edit: `results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "table_title")` extracts the text that I need, but it also extracts blank lines from all the `<tr>` tags that contain `style='display: none;'`. This significantly slows my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:not()` clause of css selector to ignore the elements contains `style='display: none;'`

```
results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[class='items']:not([style='display: none;'])")
```